# How can I find recently featured topics?

Tags: support, search, featured-questions

I recall there was some old question which was featured. Now it's no longer tagged [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) and I want to find it.

How can I find all meta posts that were [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) at any point?

Comment: I found a SEDE query that does that, and I forked it to sort by last activity first https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/1254512/meta-stack-overflow-featured-history

Comment: @SamuelLiew, thanks. Is there "featured/unfeatured date" to sort? Featuring older posts is totally possible, so would be nice to see that ordered. Browsing 177 entries (more in future) is not ace.. I still can't find the post ><

Comment: this one better? https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/1254541/meta-stack-overflow-featured-history (sorted on the creation date  when the featured tag was added (last column creationdate))

Comment: @rene, thanks, this one is better, because I can go back in time one by one post as they were announced and just looking at their creation date to find "old" ones. You can post it as the answer I guess. I still can't find topic I want, it was some old discussion, which suddenly got [meta-tag:feature] tag, could be my bad memory.. /sigh

Comment: Here are some queries which I sometimes use (on the sites which I frequent) in connection with tag management. This query shows [when and by whom](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/1105163/questions-which-had-the-given-tag-including-the-editor-who-added-it?tagname=featured) a tag was added, and [this shows removals](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/1038474/questions-which-no-longer-have-the-given-tag-including-the-editor?tagName=featured). (Take this with a grain of salt, since my SQL skills are not great.)

Comment: And here is a query for the posts where the (featured) tag was added a long time after the post was created. https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/1257301/longest-time-before-the-tag-was-added?num=100&featured (You can change the parameter num to different number of posts. And it can be used also for other tags - also I guess that is not relevant for this discussion.)